# Using python and flask-sqlalchemy, how do I return a value from my table using a dynamic variable as the column name?

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy

From my database table, I want to return multiple values. Each value is located in a different row and in a different column.

I am using a for loop to return each row. During each loop, I am successfully able to store the 'year' value in a dictionary (state_year_dict). This is because 'year' is a column name inside my table.

```
states = ['alabama', 'alaska', 'arizona', ... 'wisconsin', 'wyoming']
state_year_dict = {}
state_total_dict = {}
chosen_name = NameCounts.query.filter_by(name=name, gender=gender)
for state in states:
    state_high = chosen_name.order_by(getattr(NameCounts, state).desc()).first()
    state_year_dict[state] = state_high.year
```

During the same loop, I want to store the value from the 'state' that is currently being used in the loop. However, I can't figure out how to use the variable 'state' to pull the desired value. Here are two examples I have tried that don't work. They produce an Attribute Error saying the Model doesn't have the attribute 'state' or 'getattr'.

```
state_total_dict[state] = state_high.state
state_total_dict[state] = state_high.getattr(BabyNameCountsA, state)
```

I have looked everywhere for an answer with no luck. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you are using the `getattr()` function correctly in the `order_by()` method call. Take a closer look at  what that does.

Comment: Side note: there is probably a much more efficient way to get the numbers you are now generating, as a single SQL query rather than separate queries per state.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks for the tip. A little more research and I figured out the problem. In regards to the more efficient way to retrieve the numbers, I'm up for learning. Can you point me in the right direction of where to look?

Comment: It's a little harder to help you there because you didn't share any details about the schema. Is this a table with `year` and per-state columns, together with `name` and `gender`, and you want to find the corresponding year where the 'state' column is highest?

Comment: It also depends on the specific sql server used, to know if there is support for pivoting.

Comment: I recently watched the [modern SQL presentation on `OVER`](https://vimeo.com/289497563#t=1009s), which probably applies to your table and requirements here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a little more research, I figured out how to solve my problem. The problem line now reads:

```
state_total_dict[state] = getattr(state_high, state)
```